# uploading of an image doesnt give me broswer option to select a picture

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
     try
     {
         var _Img = new ImageBusiness();
         var imge = new ImgView { FileName = file.FileName, FileType = file.ContentType };
         imge.FileData = new byte[file.ContentLength];
         file.InputStream.Read(imge.FileData, 0, file.ContentLength);
         _Img.AddImge(imge);
         ViewBag.Result = true;
         return View ();
     }
     catch(Exception)
     {
         ModelState.AddModelError("","An error accured while uploading Image, please try again.");
         return View();
     }           
}
```

this my view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Image", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary();
    <input  name="file" /><br />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-small" value="Save Brochure" />
}
```

theres no bugs just on run time when  uploading of an image doesnt give me broswer option to select a picture.help will be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

hello i think maybe you missing type file on your input
try something like

```
<input type="file" name="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-small" value="Save Brochure" />
```